# Add Loading Screen when App Launches

Tags: ios, objective-c, loading, xcode8, launch

In my app LaunchScreen.storyboard, I put a progress bar and I want it to move (load) according to how long my app will actually start.

I have followed **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412795/how-to-use-the-progress-bar-in-the-iphone-app)**, but it's not working. I just started learning iOS programming so please bear with me.

I appreciate your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add any logical code to your launch screen as you want.
 At launch screen time, Your app is not launched at all. So your code for progress bar will not be running.

I think the better way is using a launch screen first, then show a **viewController** with a progress bar as you need.

> Also you can set launch screen story board as you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform any operation on launch screen.
Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/7441962

For that you have to create your own splash screen displayed right after the default iOS one.
Check this link for custom splash screen 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/133224/how-to-create-an-uber-splash-screen